Why can't my GNN work on such a simple task?(using its features and its neighbours' features to predict its label)
I am working on node regression prediction using Graph Neural Networks (GNNs). Currently, I am generating random graphs with 10-dimensional features for each node and no edge features. The label for each node is created by summing its own features and adding the total sum of its neighbors' features. Therefore, I believe it should be a simple task for the GNN to predict the label, and the loss should converge to zero. However, the actual loss fluctuates around 45. I have tried many methods to reduce the loss to zero, but none of them work. The model work to some degree like:
Node 0: Predicted: 9.7522, True: 12.9197
Node 1: Predicted: -6.3811, True: -9.2859
Node 2: Predicted: -19.5746, True: -7.5249
Node 3: Predicted: -77.1716, True: -17.7568
Node 4: Predicted: -2.2538, True: -5.5253
Node 5: Predicted: -9.8838, True: -4.1401
Node 6: Predicted: -10.5909, True: -8.0105
Node 7: Predicted: -5.9015, True: -9.8000
Node 8: Predicted: -20.8053, True: -30.8081
Node 9: Predicted: 5.1975, True: 2.2300
Node 10: Predicted: -14.8946, True: -8.9688
Node 11: Predicted: -4.1185, True: -4.4405
Node 12: Predicted: -21.0528, True: -25.8891
Node 13: Predicted: -3.3378, True: -8.9060
Node 14: Predicted: -6.5355, True: -7.4367
Node 15: Predicted: 29.2404, True: 30.6309
Node 16: Predicted: -37.1685, True: -64.5965
Node 17: Predicted: -6.4728, True: -4.6115
Node 18: Predicted: 8.0359, True: 9.0135
Node 19: Predicted: 25.7627, True: 29.4366
Node 20: Predicted: 26.4058, True: 20.6240
Node 21: Predicted: 13.3435, True: 12.7873
Node 22: Predicted: -47.8510, True: -53.5470
Node 23: Predicted: -12.2702, True: -21.0920
Node 24: Predicted: -33.2615, True: -29.9373
Node 25: Predicted: 19.7694, True: 26.7916
Node 26: Predicted: 3.0540, True: 7.8801
Node 27: Predicted: 22.9412, True: 23.2001
Node 28: Predicted: 10.8517, True: 11.9646
Node 29: Predicted: -9.5051, True: -14.9755

But I think the prediction should be more corresponding to the real value. I wonder why can't my GNN work on such a simple task?
My complete code is in:
https://github.com/zyg18/GNN/blob/main/GNN.py
I have tried many GNN model, like:
class SimpleGNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_node_features):
        super(SimpleGNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv = GCNConv(num_node_features, 1, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        return self.conv(x, edge_index).squeeze(-1)

class GNNWithTwoConvLayers(torch.nn.Module):
    def init(self, num_node_features):
        super(GNNWithTwoConvLayers, self).init()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 64)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(64, 64)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 16)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(16, 1)
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(0.5)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x.squeeze(-1)

class GNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def init(self, num_node_features):
        super(GNN, self).init()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 64)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 16)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(16, 1)
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(0.5)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x.squeeze(-1)


class GIN(torch.nn.Module):
def init(self, num_node_features, hidden_channels):
super(GIN, self).init()
nn1 = Sequential(Linear(num_node_features, hidden_channels), ReLU(), Linear(hidden_channels, 1))
self.conv1 = GINConv(nn1)
def forward(self, data):
    x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
    x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
    return x

It's useful to make loss converge to zero. It looks a little strange.
